# Selenium Calendar click in a specific day

Tags: selenium

How do I send a click command to a specific day in a calendar table?

```
table class name = " table-condensed"
```

but with lots of same `td class= "day"`

```
<td class="day">1</td>
<td class="day">/2</td>
<td class="day">3</td>
<td class="day">4</td>
```

the xpath is: `/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]`

I tried this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("splashy-calendar_day_up").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class=' table-condense']//tbody//tr[1]//td[5]").click()
```

But it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element by the text it contains. For example, if you want to click on the `td` tag with date "3", then use this:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_class_name(' table-condensed')
table.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[contains(text(), '3')]").click()
```

Comment: I tried. But doesn't work. I think it is because in this web page there are another table  above with number index in first column. Have another idea?

Comment: Thanks, but still not working...
ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-bb67970c0c17> in <module>
      3 driver.find_element_by_class_name("splashy-calendar_day_up").click()
      4 table = driver.find_element_by_class_name('table-condensed')
----> 5 table.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[contains(text(), '3')]").click()

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. To click on day 1.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[class=' table-condensed']/tbody/tr[1]/td[text()='1']").click()
```